# How to write a grunt task to build requirejs based Angular application

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm currently working on an Angularjs based project.I am using RequireJs library to load dependencies asynchronously.

Following is my project structure :

- index.html

  - vendors

    - angular.js
    - require.js
    - underscore.js
  - css

    - bootstrap.css
    - app.cs
  - images
  - App

    - app.js
    - signup

      - signup.controller.js
      - api.user.resource.js
      - user.service.js
      - templates

        - Login.html
    - profile

      - profile.controller.js
      - api.myprofile.resource.js
      - myprofile.resource.js
      - templates

        - profile.html

How can I combine all files inside of App folder into a single minifieds app.js file.Please help me to create a Grunt Task

Comment: this does not work like that: you must add something you tried and point to the problem you met

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/jrburke/almond. It is a minimal AMD API implementation designed for use with optimized builds.
For packaging require applications with Grunt use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs.